# Custom picklist elements

Tags: visualforce-component

I am trying to make a picklist to be able to select a field on an object and pass this field out of the component. I have created the following VF page to display this picklist however i am having issues with creating an Apex:Variable within the ComponentBody

```
<apex:page> 
<apex:form>
  <c:dynamicpicklist var="SelectedField" objectType="Opportunity">
      <!--{!SelectedField}-->
  </c:dynamicpicklist> 
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The component created is as follows:

```
<apex:component controller="DynamicPicklistController" access="global">
<!--    component variable      -->
<apex:attribute name="var" access="global" type="String" description="TODO: Describe me"/>
<!--    component attributes    --> 
<apex:attribute name="objectType" access="global" type="String" description="desc" required="true" assignTo="{!objectToCheck}"/>
<apex:attribute name="fieldType" access="global" type="String" description="desc" required="false" />


<apex:componentBody >
    <!--The Following line is failing   -->
    <apex:variable var="{!var}" value="{!SelectedField}"/>
    <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedField}" multiselect="false" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!picklistValues}" />
    </apex:selectList>

</apex:componentBody>
```

The controller used with this class is the following:

```
global class DynamicPicklistController {

global String objectToCheck {get; set;}
global String selectedField { get; set; }

global List<SelectOption> getPicklistValues() 
{
    List<SelectOption> pickListVals = new List<SelectOption>();
    //Loop through each field on the object and create a selection option.
    for(String fieldName: Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectToCheck).getDescribe().Fields.getMap().keySet())
    {
        pickListVals.add(new SelectOption(fieldName,fieldName));
    } 
    Return pickListVals; 
}
}
```

The error i am receiving when compiling the component is

> (DynamicPicklist) common.apex.runtime.bytecode.BytecodeExecutionContext cannot be cast to common.apex.runtime.impl.Execution  (Line: 1)

When i remove the `<apex:variable var="{!var}" value="{!SelectedField}"/>` line the code compiles and the picklist populates on the VF page with the fields on the given object. I have a feeling the issue may be related to the fact the picklist value is dynamically allocated and when setting the variable this is causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've it said how `var` is defined in the expression `var="{!var}"`.... I suspect you meant to have some other variable name there and the use of the name var is causing some craziness inside the compiler by conflicting with the `var` attribute... Out on a limb with this but maybe try another value there. It doesn't appear to be used elsewhere so perhaps you don't even need it?

[If you want to facilitate communication between the controller and component you can follow a design pattern where both controllers are sub-classes of a master class](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication). Using that structure you can give each a reference to the other so that they can call methods and set variables.

Comment: I've just found out that the error that i linked is caused by using the tooling api in Mavensmate, when saving using the metadata api the error is no longer given. The issue i have been having is trying to pull the choice from the selectList out of the component to be passed as a variable on the page without using a custom controller on the VF page, however looking at the link you provided this does seem like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note to the original question:

The error below showed its head again for a colleague of mine recently when using the Dev console to save a VF page with a custom component in it.

> (DynamicPicklist) common.apex.runtime.bytecode.BytecodeExecutionContext cannot be cast to common.apex.runtime.impl.Execution (Line: 1)

The error sometimes appears when saving pages using the Tooling API, to get around this you can switch to saving the file with the Metadata API or edit / save the page directly in the org.

I hope this helps anyone else encountering this error.